# POJO for api response which has key with '-'

Tags: java, api, pojo

My api response return following response body. I have to create a POJO for this api response.

```
 {
            "time-since-created": 115,
            "img_url": "<Image url>",
            "heading": "Waiting for image upload",
            "name": "How are you?",
    }
```

Private variables for other 3 will be

```
private String img_url;
private String heading; 
private String img_url;
```

But the variable for **time-since-created** gives an error

```
Can not deserialize instance
```

Comment: What library or tool do you use for deserialization?

Comment: com.fasterxml.jackson @NikolaiShevchenko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use @JsonProperty :

```
@JsonProperty("time-since-created")
private Integer timeSinceCreated;
```